# HQL query with Left Join in NHibernate 2

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql

How can I give conditions for left join in NHibernate 2.0 HQL query.

Eg in SQL.

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
left join table t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.column2 = t1.column2
```

I tried the below HQL query, but got an exception "unexpected token: with"

```
select t1 from Table1 t1
left join t1.Table2 t2 with t2.column 2 = t1.column2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `ON` statement on *(`LEFT` or any other)* `JOIN`. That condition will be injected by mapping. There is the HQL doc:

#### [14.3. Associations and joins](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-joins)

So, this HQL will work:

```
SELECT t1 from Entity1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN t1.ReferencePropertyToEntity2 t2
```

and the generated sql will be like this:

```
SELECT t1 from Table1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ReferenceColumnToTable2 = t2.Table2_ID
```

But in case, that we want to do more restrictions, we can extend **`ON`** clause with more conditions - but they will be all applied with **`AND`**

```
SELECT t1 from Entity1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN t1.ReferencePropertyToEntity2 t2 
    WITH t2.IsActive = 1
     OR t1.IsDeleted = 0
```

will result in

```
SELECT t1 from Table1 AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
     ON t1.ReferenceColumnToTable2 = t2.Table2_ID
     AND (
       t2.IsActive = 1 OR t1.IsDeleted = 0
     )
```

So, in case that we want to use WITH to totally replace ON generated by mapping, we have to go different way - with CROSS JOIN:

- [NHibernate HQL Inner Join (SQL Server,Visual C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547165/1679310)
- [How to join Two tables of two non relashinship defined columns using Nhibernate QueryOver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28689706/1679310)