# Converting SQL Query to NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate

I have a SQL Query and i am trying to convert it into Nhibernate query and run it.

SQL Query

```
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM 
    TestTable i
LEFT JOIN 
    TestTable o
ON 
    i.testColumn=o.testcolumn and i.testColumn1='TestColumn1'       
WHERE      o.StartDate <= '2016-10-28' and i.testColumn2 > 3
```

Nhibertnate Query

ObjectA is a C# object version of TestTable

```
 ObjectA o = null;
 ObjectA i = null;

 var query = Session.QueryOver(() => o)
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => i)
            .Where(() => o.testColumn == i.testColumn)
            .Where(() => i.testColumn1 == "TestColumn1")
            .Where(() => i.testColumn2 == 3
            .Where(() => o.StartDate <= '2016-10-28')
                      return query.Take(100).List();
```

Mappings

```
  public ObjectATableMap : ClassMap<ObjectA>
    {
        Schema("[Test]");
        Table("[TestTable]");

        Id(x  => x.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.TestColumn1, "TestColumn1");
     Map(x => x.TestColumn2, "TestColumn2");
     Map(x => x.StartDate ,"StartDate");

       }
```

When i run the above query i get the following message
"could not resolve property: i of: ObjectA"
Could anyone please provide me with the right hibernate Query.
Thanks

Comment: `JoinQueryOver` expects a expression with the property which has the relation. You can see an example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5420791/1486443

Comment: @RadimKohler Mappings Displayed

Comment: @Najera i'll have a look thanks

Comment: @Sike12 I tried to explain the issue in the answer.. because I expected such mapping. This simply is NOT possible... join not related tables ...

Comment: @RadimKöhler Its a self join. So i am not sure how is that not  possible?

Comment: @Sike12, I will try it again: Because NHibernate is ORM (object relational mapper) it provides querying API on top of relations. If there is no relation in your mapping (e.g. Parent as my answer suggests) there is no way how to create a JOIN even if you will name it self join. So, Either create a relation and you can query it, or use HQL as I showed.. which supports CROSS JOIN and that could solve your issue... hope now it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error:

> "could not resolve property: i of: ObjectA"

is related to statement

```
Session.QueryOver(() => o)
        .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => i)
```

because it expects, that a `class ObjectA` (o) has reference to `class ObjectA` (i). Usually parent child

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public virtual ObjectA Parent { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

If there is no relation - we cannot use `QueryOver` API. We can use HQL

- [Join Unrelated tables in Fluent Nhibernate with QueryOver or CreateCriteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32775146/1679310)
- [NHibernate HQL Inner Join (SQL Server,Visual C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547165/1679310)

It is not about nice C# API as QueryOver has, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks @Radim Kohler